# Intercept android SMS going to default inbox - BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm developing a SMS based chat application using some Telco APIS.
I am receiving SMS only from a particular number and I want to know how I can prevent SMS being sent to the the default inbox of android.

Following is the code of my SMS receiver.

Compile SDK: 27

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

        this.intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        this.context = context;
        chatlogDBAdapter = new ChatlogDBAdapter(context);
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;

                    if(senderNum.equals("77100")){
                        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                        String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        String[] messagearray = message.split(",", -1);
                        String username = messagearray[0];
                        String messagebody = messagearray[1];

                        chatlogDBAdapter.addMessage(username,username,"username",messagebody,timestamp);

                        msgusername = username;
                        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
                        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 10);
                    }


                }
                abortBroadcast();
                return;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }

    }
```

And the manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name=".IncomingSms"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of KitKat only one app can consume received sms directly with `SMS_DELIVER_ACTION`: [changelog blog here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

> Any filters for the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast in existing apps will continue to work the same on Android 4.4, but only as an observer of new messages, because unless your app also receives the SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast, you cannot write to the SMS Provider on Android 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can prevent SMS being sent to the the default inbox of android.

Its not possible unless you make your app default SMS app. Starting from Andriod Kitkat only SMS default app has capability to Write data to the provider.

You can send/receive Binary SMS which won't be visible in the Inbox/Sent box